# @app.before_request from another module

Tags: python, flask

I'm giving my fist steps on Flask and just for the fun of it I have created one more module focused on database-related stuff. So let's say I have two files:

- Main.py
- DB.py

In DB.py I have a function marked with the decorator `@app.before_request`.

However, when I execute code in Main.py, the function linked to `@app.before_request` in DB.py isn't triggered, although I have: `from DB import *`.

On the other hand, if I add the function and decorator to Main.py then it will work.

So my question is: is there any way to get this working without moving the `@app.before_request` (and the corresponding function) to Main.py?

---

**Flask community was kind enough to help a rookie like me in their IRC channel, so for future people with this problem, here's the simple solution:**

1. Move the import (of DB) to after the app definition - app = ... (thanks rknol)
2. [20:01]  xingke, if there's only a few of those, just define a function in db.py that will register the @before_request function, like here: http://bpaste.net/show/143071/ -- import the init_db function and then run it on the app once that's defined.

Comment: Can you please add the error output to the question ?

Comment: AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'db'

Comment: Can you please show some code of how you use `g.db.execute` in the main module?

Comment: g.db.execute('insert into project (uid,date) values (?,?)', [who, when])

Comment: I have reformulated the issue, probably clearer now

Comment: @xingke if you found the solution, you can answer your own question and accept it.